# Searching for a entity based on association constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, squeel

I have a model (say User), which has **many** logins.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :logins
end

class Login < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Would it be possible to find users which have a particular login (say with provider == facebook.)

I know it could be done using:

```
User.joins{logins}.where{logins.provider == "facebook"}
```

But the resultant **user** entity objects are readonly... I know I can make it writable by calling **readonly(true)** on the resultant of where{} but somehow that feels wrong.

Is there no way of doing this without the explicit **logins**?

(using squeel syntax there)